# how to create a log file with the same name as test script in pytest

Tags: pytest, python-3.6

Facing a problem in which not able to create a log file with the same name of the script .
want to create the log_file = test_support.<time_stamp>.log

i dont want to pass argument --log_file=test_support.log that works for me.

My conftest.py

```
addopts=-rp -q 
junit_family=xunit1
log_cli = True
log_cli_level = INFO
log_format = %(asctime)s %(threadName)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s
log_date_format = %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S
log_file_format = %(asctime)s %(threadName)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s
log_file_date_format = %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S
log_cli_format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:%(lineno)s:%(module)s.%(funcName)s():%(message)s'
```

test_support.py

`import pytest
import time
import logging

LOG_FILENAME = 'temp.log' +  time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H%-M-%S") + '.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME, level=logging.INFO,format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s %(funcName)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
logger = logging.getLogger(**name**)
class Test_support():

```
def test_procedure(self):
    logger.info("We are into the support call")
    assert True`
```

Tried to add the following in conftest.py but this create the log file = log.

def pytest_configure(config):
""" Create a log file if log_file is not mentioned in *.ini file"""
if not config.option.log_file:
timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
config.option.log_file = 'log.' + timestamp

def pytest_assertrepr_compare(op, left, right):
""" This function will print log everytime the assert fails"""
log.error('Comparing Foo instances:    vals: %s != %s \n' % (left, right))
return ["Comparing Foo instances:", " vals: %s != %s" % (left, right)]

Answer (score 0):

In any Python script, you can always get the absolute path of the current Python script (the file you are in) by accessing the `__file__` variable, which is a string.

You could then get your full name and strip the file extension like this

```py
import logging
import os.path
file_name = os.path.basename(__file__)
assert file_name.endswith(".py")
script_name = file_name[:-3]

logging.basicConfig(
  filename=script_name + "." + time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H%-M-%S") + '.log',
  level=logging.INFO,
  ...
)
```